# EEPROM for PXIe card

Tags: eeprom, pcie

I am working with an home made PXIe card. The PXie controller is a PEX8311. The EEPROM used to save name and configuration registers is a 93C66. I need more user space to save calibration data and replaced that unit with a 93C86 (same as the '66 but with more bits) but when I turn on the PXI chassis I don't see my card on device manager and then I cannot use it to work... somebody has an idea why?

Comment: Seems to me than PXI bus protocols, enumeration and Plug and Play support from hardware is **ON Topic** here.

Comment: This is like saying, I turn my car key but the engine won't crank. There are many reasons why the car wont start. Please provide information on your setup and be specific. Read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask If your question is not specific, it will be closed. Why? because it isn't answerable. This is a Q&A site. Please ask good questions.

Comment: Just a guess - your original EEPROM held an identifier that the device driver looks for. Without the correct identifier in the EEPROM the device driver cannot find your card.